# Installing Tally

Tags: server, .desktop

I have Ubuntu Server 12.4 Installed.  Later I installed Ubuntu Desktop on there.  I wanted to install Tally9 (Server component) which is a multi-user accounting SW, where centralized data base is managed and Tally Clients will access the data base to create invoices, vouchers etc So my question is How do I install Tally 9 on Ubuntu Server

Comment: Have a look at [How do I install and configure Wine?](/q/316025) and the [Wine App DB entry of Tally 9](//appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=18517), then report back with any particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very easy.

1. Install Wine
2. Install Tally through wine
3. Create a Data folder and share it on server
4. On client , install wine if want to run on linux.
5. Map the data folder

Comment: A little more detail would be good.